# How can I know the ascii code in c programming two dimensional string array?

Tags: c, arrays

sir.
I'm studying C programming's two dimensional string array for the first time.

I want to get the ascii code number of element.

```
#include <Stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *dict[4][2] = {{"A", "Angel"}, {"B","Ball"}, {"C", "Cindy"}, {"D", "David"}};
    printf("%d", dict[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get 65 (A's ascii code decimal number)
But I got 1866545. And this number is always changed like 108784, 180765... etc.

How can I get 65?

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! I thought about this problem for 7 days, but I couldn't find the answer by myself... I'm really thank you. Your helps is very useful!!

Answer (score 3):

Your definition is

```
const char *dict[4][2] = {{"A", "Angel"}, {"B","Ball"}, {"C", "Cindy"}, {"D", "David"}};
```

In this case,

- `dict` is `{{"A", "Angel"}, {"B","Ball"}, {"C", "Cindy"}, {"D", "David"}}`
- `dict[0]` is `{"A", "Angel"}`
- `dict[0][0]` is `"A"`

`"A"` is 2-character array `{'A', '\0'}`.
Therefore, You should use the first element of this array `dict[0][0][0]` to obtain 65 (assuming that the character code of `'A'` is 65).

(Strictly speaking, `dict[0][0]` is not an array `"A"` but a pointer pointing at the first element of `"A"`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was very difficult because it was my first time learning it, but thank you so much for telling me in detail!

Answer (score 1):

Your array is a 2d string array. It means each item is a string.
e.g. `dict[0][0]` is of type `char*`, and points to the whole string which is the `0, 0` item in `dict` (which is `"A"`).

If you want a specific character from that string, you can treat the item as a char array and use another level of indexing.
So e.g. `dict[2][1][0]` will give you the first char (at index `0`) of the `2, 1` item in `dict` (i.e., the string `"Cindy"`).

An example demonstrating that:

```
#include <Stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *dict[4][2] = {{"A", "Angel"}, {"B","Ball"}, {"C", "Cindy"}, {"D", "David"}};
    const char *specificWord = dict[0][0]; // specificWord holds pointer to string "A";
    printf("%d", specificWord[0]); // will 65 which is the ascii value for the character 'A', which is the first (and only) character in specificWord
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `dict[2][4]` is out-of-range because `dict[2]` has only 2 elements. For the reason, `dict[2][4][0]` is invalid.

Comment: @MikeCAT Well this wasn't the main point, but you're correct nevertheless. Changed.

Comment: I will study more about 2D array. Thank you very much for your help, sir! It's very helpful for me!

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
const char *dict[4][2] = { /*...*/ };
```

is a declaration of a two dimensional array with the element type `const char *`. So an expression like `dict[i][j]` where the index `i` is in the range `[0, 4)` and the index `j` is the range `[0, 2)` yields an object (pointer) of the type `const char *` that points to the first character of the corresponding string literal.

So for example you could write

```
const char *p = dict[0][0];
```

Now to get the first character of the corresponding string literal "A" that is stored in memory as a character array like

```
char string_literal_A[] = { 'A', '\0' };
```

you need to write either the expression `*p`  or the expression `p[0]`.

Substituting the pointer `p` for the expression that was used to initialize it you will get either `*dict[0][0]` or `dict[0][0][0]`.

Alternatively you could declare the array the following way

```
const char dict[4][2][6] = 
{
    {"A", "Angel"}, 
    {"B","Ball"}, 
    {"C", "Cindy"}, 
    {"D", "David"}
};
```

In such a declaration it is more visible that you need to use three indices to access an object of the element type `const char`.

You again can use either the expression `*dict[0][0]` or `dict[0][0][0]`.